# XML select single node not returning anything

Tags: c#, xml

I have the following method that is supposed to return a string that holds the calories for a given food item in an xml menu.

```
public string calorieCount(int choice)
    {
        string calCount = "250";
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);
        XmlElement root = doc.DocumentElement;
        XmlNode node = doc.SelectSingleNode("/menu/item[@name='Burger']/calories");
        string checker = node.Value;
        MessageBox.Show(checker);//returning nothing
        return checker;
    }
```

And my XML file looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<menu>
  <!-- Burger -->
  <item name="Burger">
    <name>Burger</name>
    <price>$5.99</price>
    <calories>500</calories>
    <description>A burger made with 100% angus beef and grilled to your liking. Served     with fries</description>
    <count>25</count>
  </item>
```

Why is it returning an empty string? Is my call to `SelectSingleNode` incorrect?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `InnerText` instead of `Value`

Replace

```
string checker = node.Value;
```

With

```
string checker = node.InnerText;
```